# Type Error Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-react-ui lybrary but as soon as as I import and use some element I get this error

Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

```
    import React, { Component, } from 'react'
    import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
    class FormComponent extends Component {
      render() {
      return (
        <div styleName="container">
          <Button>Click Here</Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
     export default FormComponent
```

Comment: The closing bracket of your class definition is missing. Does the problem still persist after you fixed that issue?

Comment: also why is that prop named `styleName`? A `<div>` does not have such a prop. This is probably intended to be `className`. Did you take that example from the code that is actually not working or did you make that up?

Comment: Hay. Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, neither is the problem. The bracket was not closed because I was copying the code from editor and then deleting extra stuff here on stack overflow so I deleted it accidently. styleName is because I am using babel-plugin-react-css-modules.